# Multiple Realm objects to JSON

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to convert Realm Object into JSON. My version is working but not if you want to put multiple objects into JSON. So my question is, how should you add multiple Realm Objects into JSON?

Something like that:

```
{
"Users": [
{"id": "1","name": "John"},{"id": "2","name": "John2"},{"id": "3","name": "John3"}
],
"Posts": [
{"id": "1","title": "hey"},{"id": "2","title": "hey2"},{"id": "3","title": "hey3"}
]
}
```

This is what I am doing right now:

```
func getRealmJSON(name: String, realmObject: Object, realmType: Any) -> String {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let table = realm.objects(realmType as! Object.Type)
            if table.count == 0 {return "Empty Table"}
            let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: realmObject)
            var properties = [String]()
            for (_, attr) in mirrored_object.children.enumerated() {
                if let property_name = attr.label as String! {
                    properties.append(property_name)
                }
            }
            var jsonObject = "{\"\(name)\": ["
            for i in 1...table.count {
                var str = "{"
                var insideStr = String()
                for property in properties {
                    let filteredTable = table.value(forKey: property) as! [Any]
                    insideStr += "\"\(property)\": \"\(filteredTable[i - 1])\","
                }
                let index = insideStr.characters.index(insideStr.startIndex, offsetBy: (insideStr.count - 2))
                insideStr = String(insideStr[...index])
                str += "\(insideStr)},"
                jsonObject.append(str)
            }
            let index = jsonObject.characters.index(jsonObject.startIndex, offsetBy: (jsonObject.count - 2))
            jsonObject = "\(String(jsonObject[...index]))]}"
            return jsonObject
        }catch let error { print("\(error)") }
        return "Problem reading Realm"
    }
```

Above function does like that, which is good for only one object:

```
{"Users": [{"id": "1","name": "John"},{"id": "2","name": "John2"},{"id": "3","name": "John3"}]}
```

Like this I call it out:

```
let users = getRealmJSON(name: "Users", realmObject: Users(), realmType: Users.self)
let posts = getRealmJSON(name: "Posts", realmObject: Posts(), realmType: Posts.self)
```

And I tried to attach them.

Can anybody please lead me to the right track?

Comment: Mirroring is good idea but why don't you use Codable protocol so you could manage output structure and format?

Comment: @tereks I tried to use Codable but I can not encode Realm's `List<>`. Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086660/how-to-encode-realms-list-type).

Answer (score 0):

You can use data models to encode/decode your db data:
For example you have

```
class UserEntity: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()

    @objc private dynamic var addressEntities = List<AddressEntity>()
    var addresses: [Address] {
        get {
            return addressEntities.map { Address(entity: $0) }
        }
        set {
            addressEntities.removeAll()
            let newEntities = newValue.map { AddressEntity(address: $0) }
            addressEntities.append(objectsIn: newEntities)
        }
    }
}
```

Here you hide **addressEntities** with private and declare **addresses** var with Address struct type to map entities into proper values;
And then use

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: String
    let createdAt: Date
    let addresses: [Address]
}
```

And then encode User struct any way you want